# Unable to call into C compiler when creating memory optimized table in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, memory-optimized-tables

I am trying to create my first memory optimized table using SQL Server 2014.  I first created the necessary file group and file without issue.  But when I try to create a simple table using

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSessionDevices_Optimized](
[SessionInfo_Id] [int] IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ,
[Device_Id] INT NOT NULL INDEX IX_SessionInfoOptimize_DeviceID  
) 
WITH (Memory_Optimized = ON)
```

I get the error:

Msg 41312, Level 16, State 4, Line 0
Unable to call into the C compiler. GetLastError = 1392.

I'm guessing that the SQL Server account calling the compiler does not have access to the directory where the compiler resides, but just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Forgot to mention SQL Server running on Windows Server 12.

Comment: 1392 is `ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT`. This is not the kind of error you'd expect over a simple access issue. Check the event viewer and/or the SQL Server error log for possible disk problems. This could also be caused by a file system filter interfering (antivirus/malware). You could use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/processmonitor) to dig into the exact call that's failing, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I did some search and below is what i found..

> SQLServr.exe looks  for CL.EXE under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Xtp\VC\bin folder

So this  error can happen when..

1.No access to SQLServer account on that folder
2.Bin folder name changed unintentionally..

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to heavy load on SQL Server and low memory.